# Object returning from Function vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to return an object from a function.

E.g. Ive got a function populateDog that returns Dog

So in my aspx class I want to be able to be able to pass in Lassie as the name of the dog(I have a dog class) and have the function return the object with the data it populated.

So that in my aspx class i can go lassie.color, lassie.breed

Main Goal is: lbl.txt = Lassie.Color

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
Public Function populateDog(ByVal dName As String) As dog
        dbConnection()
        Dim ObjDog As New dog(dName)
        ObjDog.sBreed = "Collie"
        Return ObjDog
    End Function
```

The idea was to have a database and I would eventually pass in an ID to query results and return it. For now though I just wanna get this understanding and move forward.

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Can you show your code so far?

Comment: @AlfonsoML Edited orginal post. Thanks - Problem is once i return the dog object I dont know how to use it. e.g. Dim Lassie = populateDog("lassie") then I cant do Lassie.sBreed?

Comment: Specify the class of the Lassie variable: Dim Lassie as dog = populateDog("lassie")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Function populateDog(ByVal dName As String) As dog
        dbConnection()
        Dim ObjDog As New dog(dName)
        ObjDog.sBreed = "Collie"
        ObjDog.Color = "White"
        Return ObjDog
    End Function
```

and

```
Dim Lassie as dog
Lassie = populateDog("Lassie")
lbl.Text = Lassie.Color
```

assuming your dog class is something like

```
Class dog
    Public sBreed As String
    Public Color As String
    ' other properties and functions
End Class
```

Comment: @AlfonsoML Is it better to have my populateDog inside the Dog class or should I have it in my database class? Thanks

Comment: @kb88 It would fit better in your database class.